# Adding an MVC project to an existing web application with .Net 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an existing old WebForms application.

I need to add an MVC project.

The server where it is hosted is Windows 2003 R2, so only .Net 4 can be used. 
And we use VS 2017.

I tried to add the project, but there is only "Empty" option available, and the "MVC" checkbox below is disabled, as well as "Web Forms" and "Web API".

Could you please tell how I can add an MVC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you need to download the [ASP.NET MVC 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683) installer.

The bigger question is, why not spin up an additional webserver which can support newer versions of .net?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this installer better than using NuGet?

Comment: I installed MVC 4 on my machine. But nothing changed. What should I do to be able to add an MVC project? I cannot do it even on a brand new solution.

Comment: Did you restart Visual Studio/reboot? I suspect that's necessary for it to pick up new packages.